# Make NSToolbarItem become first responder

Tags: swift, macos, first-responder, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

In my MacOS app, there is an `NSSearchField` in the Toolbar. I want to enable users to focus it by pressing `CMD+F` (the same behavior that is used in many of Apple’s apps). I created an `NSMenuItem` with a key equivalent of `CMD+F` – it calls the following function, which is supposed to make the `NSSearchField` first responder.

```
@IBAction func focusFilter(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    self.view.window?.toolbar?.items.first(where: { (item) -> Bool in
        return item.itemIdentifier.rawValue == "Search"
    })?.view?.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

When pressing `CMD+F` it seems as if the `NSSearchField` becomes the first responder for a very short time (the title starts moving to the left), but then it loses focus before the Focus Ring appears (the `NSSearchField` does not refuse first responder).

I also tried using the `NSToolbarItem`’s `menuFormRepresentation.view`, with the same result.

How can I make an `NSToolbarItem` become first responder? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: From the documentation of `becomeFirstResponder`: "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.".

Comment: @Willeke Ugh, so simple! I am relatively new to macOS programming, so sometimes I miss the obvious stuff. Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Willeke, the right solution is not the use `becomeFirstResponder`, but to use `NSWindow makeFirstResponder:` instead. It works fine with this code:

```
@IBAction func focusFilter(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    if let searchItem = self.view.window?.toolbar?.items.first(where: { (item) -> Bool in
        return item.itemIdentifier.rawValue == "Search"
    }) {
        self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(searchItem.view)
    }
}
```